# Custom JSON Classifier for Glue reads schema but can't read data with Athena

Tags: json, amazon-athena, aws-glue

So I have a json file that has this structure:

```
 {"campaigns":
    [
         {'account_id': '123', 'name': 'abc'},
         {'account_id': '456', 'name': 'def'}
    ]
 }
```

In my custom classifier for Glue I use a JSON path of:

```
$.campaigns[*]
```

When I run the crawler I see the properties of JSON object are imported correctly to Glue Data catalog.  The problem is that when I use Athena to query
the table all the columns come back empty except for my partition columns.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to put the json data in single line. Please also go through the [url](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-json-athena/) below if it matches with the possible issues listed.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/error-json-athena/

Comment: Yea after reading the link you sent me, it looks like I'll have to change the structure.  Thanks!